# Testar Páginas dentro do padrão de carregamento 5 segundos

Tags: javascript, html, css

Vou selecionar alguns sites a dedo, para catalogar e disponibilizar posteriormente e tenho em mente priorizar usuários que utiliza mini-modem USB 2G/3G no Computador Pessoal (PC), no qual a conexão é um tanto limitada.

Para isso preciso saber o tipo de WebSite que eles terão melhor visualização e usabilidade, se é ou não instânanea apresentação do conteúdo dessas páginas.

Vamos utilizar um campo de texto onde será inserida uma URL qualquer da Web, e o botão para o qual irá direcionar a abertura desta dentro de um ***iframe***.

## A lógica

Imagine por exemplo que, dentro da página onde verificará se é igual ou superior a 5 segundos o tempo `onload`. Caso seja maior que 5 segundos, então descontinua o carregamento da URL e emite um `alert();` do tipo **"Huuumm! Esta página foge dos nossos padrões 2G(EDGE)"**

Mas se o número de segundos for menor então permita o carregamento e ao fim emita outro tipo de `alert();` algo do tipo **"Ok! Esta página é válida para conexões 2G(EDGE)"**

## Lembrete

> A página que verifica contém os scripts e um `<iframe></iframe>`, quando comparada o tempo de carga será feita uma das duas ações dentro `<iframe></iframe>`

A parte que fica obscura pra mim é, como parar o carregamento de um url dentro de um iframe.

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?:

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se isto é a maneira mais correcta de resolver o problema, e se não vale mais o teu servidor fazer um primeiro load da página, fazer um timestamp antes e depois, e considerar se o user vai poder fazer o load ou nao; No entanto, podes sempre fazer um check ao document do iframe de X em X tempo;

```
function frameHasDocument(frameID) {
  return document.frames[frameID] && document.frames[frameID].document !== nulll;
  // se o frame.document é nulo, a pagina ainda nao fez loaded
}
var maxIterations = 10; // 10 iteraçoes a 1000ms cada = 10segundos
function takingTooLong() {
    if (maxIterations === 0 && !frameHasDocument('id-do-frame')) {
    document.frames['id-do-frame'].src = null;
    alert('demorou.');
  } else {
    console.log('passing..');
    setTimeout(takingTooLong,1000);
    maxIterations--;
  }
}
```

Continuo a pensar que será mais correcto o servidor decidir o tempo de load, gravar esse valor para ser usado no futuro, e dizer ao user se vai ou nao fazer um bom load.